# Django: how do i request username in SessionWizardView?

Tags: python, django, view, request

I have a problem. in my code i have to use `class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):`

and I have encountered a problem. I have literally no idea how do i get username of currently logged in user :(

```
@login_required
def invite(request):
    return render_to_response('invite.html', {'full_name': request.user.username})

class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "invite.html"

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)

        return render_to_response('invitedone.html', {'form_data': form_data})

def process_form_data(form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]

    #code code code...       
    #code code code...
    #code code code...

    return form_data
```

in `def process_form_data` i would like to be able to put username into string and then insert it into email. but how do i get it? I can't use `self` and `request` because they are not defined there.

Please help me solve this one

Comment: Well, that should be a sign to you that your design is wrong. If you need those variables, why not pass them to the function? But you should also ask yourself why you have process_form_data as a separate function in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do this:

```
class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "invite.html"

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list, self.request.user)

        return render_to_response('invitedone.html', {'form_data': form_data})
```

And do not forget to [require the login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views) for the wizard view as well.

Anyway as [@Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) said you may also want to rethink your design and make the process_form_data part of the view.

Comment: hello, this helps, and to the second part of the answer - i also cant use 
`@login_required` , because then i am getting this error:

`AttributeError at /accounts/loggedin/invite`
`'ContactWizard' object has no attribute 'user'`

Comment: Glad to hear! Check where you put the `login_required` decorator. For class based views you have two options: the first is to call the decorator in the urlconf, which is the one used in the link I added, the second option is to decorate the dispatch method of the view using a [method decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class).

Comment: Thank you, I have used the second option you suggested.

Comment: If you are using multiple class based views you may like the mixin approach: [here is and example for the login](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2442/) and a broader discussion on mixins [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/mixins/)